# html input type number is not taking 0.

Tags: html

My Html input type number is not accepting 0 as a first input. It only accept 1 to 9 digit as a first input. Here is my code

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="signup_phone" id="signup_phone" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Phone', 'service-finder'); ?>">
```

If i give input 120124214 it accept. But if I give 0124452 it is not taking my input.

Comment: This isn’t problem of html. There is no validation on the input as far as your example goes.

Comment: Please be confirm not applied any filter or format for this field because it is working fine for me. If not then use type="text" then make typecast in number.

Comment: Because, technically things starting with 0 are not real numbers. If you parse them, the leading 0 is omitted. The concepts of number and phone number collide here in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple code

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using?  Works fine for me.  Test it here.

```js
function validate(){
  alert(document.forms[0].signup_phone.value);
  }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="signup_phone" id="signup_phone" placeholder="something">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with phone number validation. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49187726/edit).

> NANP numbers take the form NXX NXX XXXX where N is a digit 2-9 and X is a digit 0-9. Additionally, area codes and exchanges may not take the form N11 (end with two ones) to avoid confusion with special services except numbers in a non-geographic area code (800, 888, 877, 866, 855, 900) may have a N11 exchange.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode === 0 || /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));">
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mxdjxY

Comment: it works when user type number . But if I type number with another sign in another place and paste it in input field it tale this `-` too. like 46874-156589